# React Testing Library - Unable to find the element with data-testid

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library

I am following the docs for react-testing-library to find if the element with `data-testid` attribute is rendered or not.

The react-testing-library is not able to find the element  even though it exists.

**TEST**

```
test('Renders step based on the active step', () => {
    render(<RenderStep />, { initialState: { implOnboard: initialState } });
  });
  expect(screen.getByTestId('step-1')).toBeDefined(); //  THROWS ERROR ❌
}
```

**COMPONENT**

```
 // redux
  const { activeStep } = useSelector((state) => state.implOnboard);

  const renderStep = () => {
    switch (activeStep) {
      case 1:
        console.log('Rendering this '); //  THIS IS GETTING LOGGED TOO!
        return (
          <div data-testid="step-1">
            <StepOne />
          </div>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <div data-testid="step-2">
            <StepTwo />
          </div>
        );
    }
  };
  return <React.Fragment>{renderStep()}</React.Fragment>;
```

**ERROR**

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="step-1"]
```

Comment: In your test file just add this `console.log(screen.debug(null, Infinity));` before your expect and check whether you are seeing the DOM getting printed correctly .

Comment: Any reason why the `expect` statement is outside the `test()` block?

Answer (score 69):

Please use the `queryByTestId` instead `getByTestId` for the case. It will work.

Comment: Any reason why it works with queryByTestId and not with getByTestId?

Comment: @ArpitGupta its not actually working, its just ignoring the error, I console logged queryByTestId it returned null which means the element is still not found but this function does not throw an error instead returns null due to which test cases are passing.

Comment: Like Kashan said, This is wrong and I explain why on my answer

Answer (score 45):

The answer from Elena is wrong and just masks the error. Using `queryByTestId` will return null if the element is not found, instead of an error when using `getByTestId`, and the assertion will actually be:

```
  expect(null).toBeDefined();
```

and this WILL pass. This is not testing anything. `toBeDefined()` fails only if the element is equal to undefined and it passes for everything else.

If OP wants to actually check if that element is NOT present they should do:

```
  expect(screen.queryByTestId('step-1')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

The original error from OP is probably happening because the expect is outside the test block.

Comment: This is the appropriate answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can find more information on those methods [in the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about), they explain differences between 'get' 'query' and 'find'

Answer (score 23):

Adding to Elena's response, we need to use `queryByTestId` because, `queryByTestId` returns `null` value if element is not found instead of throwing error unlike `getByTestId`. Here's the image that explains when to use different methods.

Sometimes you get an error even when using this `queryBy`, so please check other code before this statement.

[image]

**Reference** - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yghw9FkNGsc&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gm4_-5UsNmLqMosM-dzuvQ&index=5&ab_channel=TheNetNinja

Comment: Incorrect, it hides the error because `expect(null).toBeDefined()` returns true

Answer (score 3):

For those using React Native Web, you will need to use `testID` which will compile down to `data-testid` on the element. It needs to be on a react native element not your custom one (pass it through as a prop and put it on a View, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just an typo instead of data-testid i wrote dat**e**-testid

Comment: I can't believe I did the same thing :(